# Price-shopping assistance - disagree on the Super Kodiak question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This question https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13590/all-the-bear-archery-super-kodiak-models-with-a-64-amo-length was set on hold because of price-shopping assistance.

> put on hold as off-topic by (...) yesterday
>
> This question appears to be off-topic for this site. While what’s on-
>   and off-topic is not always intuitive, you can learn more about it by
>   reading the help center. The users who voted to close gave this
>   specific reason:
>
> "Questions seeking price-shopping assistance are off-topic because
>   they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation
>   and the specific problem you're trying to solve." – (...)
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center,
>   please edit your question.

---

> Questions seeking price-shopping assistance

I don't mention a single price-shopping assistance in the question. I asked for a (more or less historical) list of bows with the amo-length of 64 ". Bear archery bows have great emotional value for collectors and archers all around the globe!

> (...) because they tend to become obsolete quickly

Please, someone has to explain me why a bow model with 64 " amo length shouldn't have this length anymore in the future? :)

> describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve

That's what I did. I basically want a bear bow with 64 " AMO length. To know and compare them, I need a list which models were produced in this length.

---

I don't really see how I've violated the rules? How can I rephrase the question to make it more clear?

Comment: You know that the obsolete refers to the shopping/pricing info not the item itself, c'mon

Comment: Your first question is: "Is there a 64 " hard-rock maple Super Kodiak in the current product range of Bear Archery?". You use "current" yourself, pointing to the fact that this might be outdated soon. The second part, asking for historical models that ever existed is in my opinion valid, as this will be true at all times. It is a list-type question, but that can be addressed by e.g. a community answer.

Comment: @imsodin Edited the question. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't one of the people who voted to close the question but I did vote not to reopen it.

The reason why I think it was closed and the reason why I voted not to reopen it is because it is a shopping question that needs to be posed to the appropriate dealers/manufacturer. I think that is why the "Price-shopping" was chosen as the close reason. People saw a pure shopping question and chose a shopping related close reason.

One way that I could see the question being improved is if you posed it in a way that doesn't sound like you're disappointed in your color choices. Something along the lines of:

> I noticed that the Super Kodiak from Bear Archery bow with a 64" draw only is available in black-phenolic and doesn't offer a maple version. Is there something about the longer draw length that prevents them from using maple or is this just an arbitrary decision based on perceived demand?

This shifts the question away from a shopping question to a question that deals with the suitability of the material, and can lead to meaningful insights into archery instead of just promoting a product while lamenting limited color options. Of course going to the manufacturer is probably still the best recourse to get a good answer to the question....

Comment: I've edited the question. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Hi Erik. With the most recent edit, it's obviously not a price-shopping question. I'm just wondering if there are other close reasons it falls into because it would be hard for us to answer the part about "whole history of the bows." @OddDeer, I didn't vote either way, and am not picking on you or the question, just curious so I can learn something.

Comment: @Sue You have to understand that Bear Archery bows (especially historical ones) are extreme valuable collector items. That's why it's not that "crazy" to wish for such a list. :)

Comment: @Sue I agree in its current form it doesn't read like a shopping question to me. It is currently a list question which is discouraged in some stacks but allowed on others with well defined boundaries and a slow growth rate. I'm not sure of the policy here though.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I appreciate you taking the time to give me your perspective!

Answer (score 1):

"Questions for the manufacturer" is not a valid close reason.  Probably half the gear questions on this site could be termed a "question for the manufacturer".  If you go back, some questions where actually answered by users calling/emailing a manufacturer and getting official answer.

"Price comparison" is a valid close reason.  However this question clearly is NOT price comparison.

The question is, at it's core, asking about whether or not a thing exists.  This is completely valid on that angle.  One *could* argue that it is so esoteric that is it not valid for that reason.